# what should be @Produces for a list of map

Tags: java, rest, annotations

I have a Rest API which returns a list of map like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>
```

I have put @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) in top of my method but as soon as I run the project I get this error:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>>.
```

I don't know what to put for @Produces

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to some wrapper like

```
public class SomeWrapper{ 
     private List<Map<String,Object>> data; 
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some more detail. I don't understand what to do @Ashish Srivastava

Comment: You have to write a wrapper class which contains your map as the class field. like

`public class SomeWrapper{
private List<Map<String,Object>> data;
}`